# Calculator not functioning properly

Tags: python, calculator

Hey I'm trying to make a small calculator for a project, however I'm struggling to get the code to work.

```
import time

a = 100
b = 1

while a > b:
     print("Please select an operation. ")
     print("1. Multiply")
     print("2. Divide")
     print("3. Subtract")
     print("4. Add")
     b = 200
     x = int(input("Please enter your operation number. "))
     if x == 4:
          y = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
          z = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
          finaladd = (y+z)
          print(finaladd)
          c = input("Would you like to do another calculation? ")
     if c == 'yes' or c == 'Yes':
           a = 500
     if c == 'no' or 'No':
           b = 1000

if x == 2:     
     y2 = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
     z2 = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
     finaladd2 = (y2/z2)
     print(finaladd2)

if x == 3:
     y3 = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
     z3 = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
     finaladd3 = (y3-z3)
     print(finaladd3)

if x == 1:
       y4 = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
       z4 = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
       finaladd4 = (y4*z4)
       print(finaladd4)
```

When I try to run operation 4, I want the code to ask if you would like to run another calculation, if you answer with 'yes' it will repeat the statement again. However all it does is stop the code. Sorry if it's obvious I'm quite new to coding.

Comment: use a while loop

Comment: Is this your real code? There seem to be some indentation issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
import time

a = 100
b = 1

while a > b:
    print("Please select an operation. ")
    print("1. Multiply")
    print("2. Divide")
    print("3. Subtract")
    print("4. Add")
    b = 200
    x = int(input("Please enter your operation number. "))
    if x == 4:
        y = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
        z = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
        finaladd = (y+z)
        print(finaladd)
        c = input("Would you like to do another calculation? ")
        if c == 'yes' or c == 'Yes':
            a = 500
        elif c == 'no' or c == 'No':
           b = 1000
   
    elif x == 2:     
         y2 = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
         z2 = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
         finaladd2 = (y2/z2)
         print(finaladd2)
    
    elif x == 3:
         y3 = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
         z3 = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
         finaladd3 = (y3-z3)
         print(finaladd3)
    
    elif x == 1:
           y4 = int(input("Please enter your first number. "))
           z4 = int(input("Please enter your second number. "))
           finaladd4 = (y4*z4)
           print(finaladd4)
```

Comment: thank you so much, i don't know why elif made a difference but i'm just glad it worked. thank you so so much

Comment: Glad to Help... Actually the main issue was in line (c == 'no' or 'No')... the correct way should be (c == 'no' or c == 'No')... so what happened in your code was basically regardless of input yes/no... both a & b values were updating to 500 & 1000 respectively & code stopped at (while a<b) condition in 2nd attempt, even if users say "yes"...  Hope this Helps... Thanks...

Comment: Thanks so much, it annoys how only a small mistake can break a program. But again thank you for explaining it. :)